# Unable to read csv file from Amazon s3

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

My requirement is to read the csv file from Amazon s3 using javascript and to make it as html table data.
I have tried the following html code but it was not working:

```js
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#load_data').click(function(){
     alert("inside click");
      $.ajax({
       url:"https://s3Url/TestData_CSV.csv",
       dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin, content-type, accept"
        }, 
       success:function(data)
       {
        var tbl_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
        for(var count = 0; count<tbl_data.length; count++)
        {
         var cell_data = tbl_data[count].split(",");
         table_data += '<tr>';
         for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
         {
          if(count === 0)
          {
           table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
          }
          else
          {
           table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
          }
                }
         }
         table_data += '</tr>';
         table_data += '</table>';
        $('#tbl_details').html(table_data);
        }
        
       });
      });
     });
    </script>
```

```html
 <html>
     <head>
      <title>Details</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="table-responsive">
        <h1 align="center">Details</h1>
        <br />
        <div align="center">
         <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="tbl_details">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>

    </html>
```

But,I was getting **net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)** error on running the html. Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: CORS failures don't give 403 errors, at least. Can you access the same URL when you just paste it into the address bar?